# Ajax call not getting any response

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, vuejs2

I have an Ajax call that validates an input data and show the response to the user. It usually takes less than five minutes to run and send the response, but it may vary depending on how much data I'm validating. When I run from my computer, I always get the response, but when the client runs the same application from his computer on his network, he never gets an answer. So he waits ten minutes without an answer and then press F5 to get the validation log.
I am using VueJS and below is my request.

```
this.$http.get(url).then(
    response => {
        console.log("success");
    }, 
    error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
)
.finally(function(){
    console.log("finally");
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

We're both using Chrome and looking at his console, none of the above logs are shown and there are the following errors: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED, net::INTERNET_DISCONNECTED.

Is there a way to force an answer without specifying a timeout? Are those errors above related to the problem? If so, how can I fix them?

Comment: Use axios. its easy

Comment: 5 minutes is a _long_ time. Why does it take so long? It should be 5 seconds, max

Comment: @JeremyThille, it is 5 minutes to run the validation and return the response to the user.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question why is it so long? Even with several databases calls, it should take 5 seconds tops, even closer to 0.5 second, but not 5 _minutes_. I mean, who's gonna wait 5 entire minutes for a server to respond? :) Have you ever, in your life, clicked a button and waited 5 entire minutes for the response?

Comment: @JeremyThille, like I said in my question, for me it works, so yes I've clicked and waited five minutes until it finished running. That's not the point here, but this is part of a supply chain software and what the validations does is check if the user has provided all the necessary data and if its is valid for the next step. It gets data from almost a hundred tables and looks for any inconsistency in the data.

Comment: waiting for 5mins is crazy... but if it is so , so it is :D